# SQLDeveloper - Custom Refactor --> Surround With

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Quite often I need to comment out a line or a section of a line in my SQL.  In most cases my queries will be loaded into another tool like BIRT which converts the query into a single line.  Because of this, I can't just use the single line comment (--) and must use a multi-line comment (/*  */).

Is there any way at all to surround a block with block comments?  For example, I'd like to be able to easily turn this:

```
select *
from foo, count(*)
where foo.bar = '1'
  and foo.baru != foo.bar
  and foo.barid in
    (select barid from bar where foo = 1)
group by foo
order by foo desc;
```

Into this:

```
select *
from foo, count(*)
where foo.bar = '1'
  and foo.baru != foo.bar
  and foo.barid in
    (select barid from bar /*where foo = 1*/)
group by foo
order by foo desc;
```

[image: Refactor --> Surround with in right click menu]

Thanks!

Comment: not as context action but maybe firstly making '--' multi line comment by selecting more lines and ctrl + / and then some custom formatting or plugin?